# Javascript to fill browser with one image

Tags: javascript, image

I've got a simple web page containing one image and some text below it. Kind of (simplyfied)

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="image.jpg" width="1920" height="1024">
    <br/>
    <p>Image description</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I want the image to show fully in the browser, regardless of size and device. The rest of the screen should be black (or any other color), the text should be below so the viewer could scroll down. 
I guess this could be done in Javascript but I honestly do not have a clue how to start. I do have the image size, but of course I neither know the browser resolution nor how to resize an image onscreen.

How can I fill the browser with the image?

[Update] Some clarification: The image might be in landscape or Portrait orientation and I always want to show the image full. So for an image in portait orientation the image should be centered on the screen with height=screen height and the space left and right of the image should be some solid color (black?). 
And the image should keep it's original aspect ratio, no distortion.

[Update 2] With help of Thomas code I got this code, which is nearly there:

```
<img id="imageX" src="stjuergenkirchenachts.jpg"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var imgWidth = 4912.0;
 var imgHeight = 7360.0;
 var scale = Math.min(window.innerHeight / imgHeight, window.innerWidth / imgWidth);
 var image = document.getElementById('imageX');
 image.style.height = (imgHeight * scale) + 'px';
 image.style.width = (imgWidth * scale) + 'px';
</script>
```

demrks answer to achieve this just with css is cool, but I do not want the image as background for seo and usability reasons (eg no alt tag).

Comment: remove the width and height attributes and add style="width: 100%;"

Comment: Do you want to stretch that image to 100% height / width no matter what the image proportions?

Comment: Try putting div instead and using image as a background with 'background-size:cover' (CSS3)

Comment: No, the aspect ratio should be kept, no distortion. And width=100% does not work for images in portrait orientation, the bottom part of the image would be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript you could try it this way.

First, name your image element id='imageX'

```
 var image = document.getElementById('imageX');
 image.style.height = parseInt(window.innerHeight) + 'px';
 image.style.width = parseInt(window.innerWidth) + 'px';
```

but doing it with css statement background: cover; -webkit-background:cover; will probably look better, as it shouldn't distort the image.

Comment: background:cover does cut off the bottom part of the picture if it is higher than the screen, so this does not work for me.
I'll try the javascript as soon as I get a clue how to implement it in the html code (got no JS knowledge).

Comment: Nearly there - now I just need to get rid of the default margin between browser window and image.

Comment: For that you just need to set your body element to something like this:  body{margin:0;padding:0;}

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use Javascript to resize the image. You can use basic CSS for it.

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

You could use something like this in your CSS file and all images will resize if their parent is smaller than the image dimensions.

Here is the corresponding [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8y7jD/embedded/result/). Try resizing your browser window to...

**EDIT:**
As mentioned in the comments you probably want the image to be fullscreen, but keep the image dimensions untouched. But even this effect you could solve with plain CSS: You'll have to set the image as a "background-image" and set the "background-size" to "cover" (image gets cropped) or "contain". If you need to support IE8 ([which doesn't support background-size](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts)) you'll have to use a polyfill or use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect, if the browser has support for "background-size" and provide a JS fallback.

```
.anyelement {
    background-image: url("test.jpg");
    background-size: cover; /* or "contain" */
    background-position: center center; /* center image */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

You can find the [JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SBRaP/) (for "cover") or [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/SBRaP/1/) (for contain).

**EDIT 2**
You asked if it is possible to have text underneath your fullscreen image. Sure, just create other divs below your div, which contains the image. I updated the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SBRaP/2/) with an example text if you scroll down.

Comment: In what way is this 100% height / width?

Comment: "The rest of the screen should be black (or any other color)". This doesn't sound like 100% height / width to me.

Comment: _fill browser with image_ does. _Now I want the image to show fully in the browser_ does too.

Comment: If the image height is larger than the screen height the bottom of the image will be cropped off, but I want to show the full image (smaller in this case).

Comment: Background-size: Cover cuts the bottom of the picture off, too, if it's higher than the screen height.

Comment: @Sam use "background-size: contain" instead. You can also use "background-position: center center;" to position your image in the center of the window. Hope that helps.

Comment: I want the text to be below the image so the visitor can scroll down - if I use the background it will be on the image and the image cannot be scrolled away, which is not what I had in mind. I don't think background is what I need.

Comment: I updated the fiddle with some text underneath the fullscreen image: http://jsfiddle.net/SBRaP/2/

Comment: Just seen your 2nd update, cool way to achieve it without js - pity I can't choose two right answers!

Answer (score 0):

`<img src="image.jpg" width="1920" height="1024" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">` if you want the image to be as wide as the screen and keep its ratio.

If you want to image to distort and fill the entire screen you can use jQuery $(window).width() & $(window).height() to get screen size and set img width/height based on it: `$("img.yourImgClassHere").css({"width" : $(window).width(), "height":$(window).height()});`

Comment: If the picture height is larger than the screen height, the bottom of the picture will be cut off, so in some cases this does not show the full image, just a crop.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can set the image to maximum width and height of any device

```
element.style.backgroundSize = screen.availWidth +'px '+ screen.availHeight+'px';
```